# How to find the non-differentiable point(s) of a given continuous function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions

For example, the non-differentiable point of the function $f(x)=|x|$ is at $x=0$.
How to find the non-differentiable points of a continuous function that is defined numerically?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If we define `f[x]` e.g. like this:

```
f[x_] := Abs[x]
```

the following returns interesting points:

```
Reduce[ 
    Limit[(f[x + h] - f[x])/h, h -> 0, Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals, Direction -> -1] != 
    Limit[(f[x + h] - f[x])/h, h -> 0, Assumptions -> x ∈ Reals, Direction -> 1],  x]
```

> ```
> x == 0
> ```

Let's try another function defined with `Piecewise`, e.g.

```
g[x_] := Piecewise[{{x^2, x < 0}, {0, x == 0}, {x, 1 > x > 0}, 
                    {1, 2 >= x >= 1}, {Cos[x - 2] + x - 2, x > 2}}]
```

then we needn't use `Assumptions` in `Limit`:

```
Reduce[ Limit[ (g[x + h] - g[x])/h, h -> 0, Direction -> -1] != 
        Limit[ (g[x + h] - g[x])/h, h -> 0, Direction -> 1], x]
```

> ```
>  x == 0 || x == 1 || x == 2
> ```

```
pts = {x, g[x]} /. {ToRules[%]};

Plot[ g[x], {x, -5/4, 3}, PlotStyle -> Thick, 
      Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.023], Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

One should be careful when working with `Piecewise` since `Reduce` may produce errors when weak inequalities (`LessEqual`) are involved. For this reason we added `{0, x == 0}` in the definition of the function `g`.

Comment: But when `f[x_] := Abs[x]`, I run your code and get false, not 0(12.1.1).

Comment: @Ordinaryusers68  This answer had provided correct solution in version $9.0.1$ and formerly. And it should work correctly until now. However  `RealAbs` would have been 
 introduced   in $11.1$ and consequently `Abs` changed as well as `Limit` in version $11.2$. Example with function `f` should be changed using `Assumptions -> x>=0` and `Assumptions -> x < 0` to avoid misleading results. However example with `g` (using `Piecewise`) works correctly.

Answer (score 7):

Here is an approach that you can use for numerical functions that at least have a left and right derivative. If such a function isn't differentiable in a point that is equivalent to the left and right derivatives being unequal, so
look at the left and right finite difference approximation of the derivative, and see where they disagree.

```
rightd[f_, h_, x_] := (f[x + h] - f[x])/h
leftd[f_, h_, x_] := (f[x] - f[x - h])/h

f[x_?NumericQ] := If[x < .13, 0 , x - .13 ]

Plot[Abs[leftd[f, 0.1, x] - rightd[f, 0.1, x]], {x,-1,1}, PlotRange->All]
```

[image: plot]

Using this you can use some numerical maximization on `Abs[leftd[f, h, x] - rightd[f, h, x]]`, perhaps with successively smaller `h` to avoid false positives.

Answer (score 1):

Some things change to better since 12.2

```
FunctionDiscontinuities[D[RealAbs[x], x], x]
```

> `RealAbs[x] == 0`

```
FunctionDiscontinuities[CantorStaircase'[x], x]
```

> `False`and a warning "FunctionDiscontinuities::unkds: Warning: The set of discontinuities may be incomplete due to missing domain and discontinuity information for some of the functions involved."

and since 10.0

```
FunctionDomain[RealAbs'[x], x, Reals]
```

> `x < 0 || x > 0`