# How to determine if a piecewise function is differentiable?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

In particular, I've this function in R^2:

```
f = Piecewise[ { {(x y) / (x^2 +y^2), x != 0 && y != 0}, {0, x == 0 && y == 0} } ]
```

Now I would like to determine if the function is differentiable at point (1,2) without using the definition.
I remember that in Wolfram alpha there's an simply "is differentiable?", but there I can't set an specific point..
So can I use same simple mathematica function?
Ps I know use the definition of differentiability, but at the moment I need something faster if possible

Comment: [Here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/225100/42417)'s a similar question.

Answer (score 3):

I think you might find the answer given in this link useful, it gives an example of a piecewise function and how to find the non-differentiable points

[How to find the non-differentiable point(s) of a given continuous function?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/how-to-find-the-non-differentiable-points-of-a-given-continuous-function)

It is only a matter of generalizing for two variables, and checking if that specific point you are looking for is part of the non-differentiables or not

Hope that helps.