# Is there a functionality to analytically find discontinutites of function?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, discontinuity

I would like know whether it is somehow possible to analytically get discontinuities of a given function on a given interval (possibly with some reasonable assumption of the function otherwise being well-behaved)

To give an example I would like a function `Discontinuities` that behaves something like this:

```
( *In *) Discontinuities[Sign[x], {x,-1,1}]
(* Out *) {0}

(* In *) Discontinuities[Floor[2x], {x,-1,1}]
(* Out *) {-1/2,0,1/2}

(* In *) Discontinuities[CDF[BinomialDistribution[2, 1/2], x], {x, -1, 3}]
(* Out *) {0,1,2}
```

Comment: This is a slightly related [discussion](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/32872/how-to-find-the-non-differentiable-points-of-a-given-continuous-function)

Comment: Interesting. Something similar could work using the analytical definition of discontinuity. How could I make a subexpression like `Limit[Sign[x], x -> 0, Direction -> "FromAbove"]` not directly evaluate, so I can `Reduce` it for `x` in a logical formula requiring limit `"FromAbove"` and `"FromBelow"` to be different at point `x`?

Comment: There's one in the Wolfram Function Repository [here](https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/FunctionDiscontinuities).

Comment: Specifying the interval in the form `{x, -1, 1}` is ambiguous as to whether the endpoints should be included. Including intervals as constraints (e.g., `{f[x], -1 < x < 1}` or `{f[x], -1 <= x <= 1}`as used in "FunctionDiscontinuities") eliminates the ambiguity.